# JDBC updating specific cells of a column based off of unique id

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to update the first name, last name, and email of a specific user based off of their unique user ID.

I'm making the following query to do that but I'm getting an exception telling my my syntax is incorrect. I'm fairly new to JDBC and MYSQL but here's what i did:

```
PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE user_table WHERE userTableID = "+ userId+ "(first_name, last_name, email) values (?, ?, ?)");
ps.setString(1, newFirstName);
ps.setString(2, newLastName);
ps.setString(3, newEmail);
ps.execute();
```

Update: with some guidance I decided to do it like this instead and it worked.

```
PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE user_table SET first_name= ?, last_name=?, email=?" + "WHERE userTableID = ?");
ps.setString(1, newFirstName);
ps.setString(2, newLastName);
ps.setString(3, newEmail);
ps.setInt(4, userId);
ps.execute();
```

Comment: Print out the full statement of your query, and it should be obvious what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE user_table set first_name=?,last_name=?,email=? WHERE userTableID = ?");
                ps.setString(1, newFirstName);
                ps.setString(2, newLastName);
                ps.setString(3, newEmail);
                ps.setString(4, userId);
                ps.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

correct syntax of update is `UPDATE table_name SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;`
try this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE user_table set (first_name, last_name, email) values (?, ?, ?)  WHERE userTableID = \""+ userId+ "\"");
```

Comment: You should really also bind the `userId` variable (not just the other three).

Comment: no it doesn't need necessarily! your search is based on userId and the other variables are going to be changed

Comment: I'm still getting an exception. This is what i'm getting for the exception. 

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(first_name, last_name, email) values ('asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf', 'asdfasdf')  WHER' at line 1

Comment: based on your comment, there is a single quotation `'` before `(` which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

In second one there may be problem due to space  provide a single space after `email=?` as below

```
PreparedStatement ps =conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE user_table SET first_name= ?, last_name=?, email=? " 
                      + "WHERE userTableID = ?");
                        ps.setString(1, newFirstName);
                        ps.setString(2, newLastName);
                        ps.setString(3, newEmail);
                        ps.setInt(4, userId);
                        ps.execute();
```